# Scripts works in console but not in cron?

Tags: php, download, console, cron

I have a PHP script that pulls image urls from a csv file and downloads them to our server.  When I run this script in console everything works great!  Problem is when this script is called from CRON it just keeps giving null results:

```
<b>Warning</b>: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in <b>/home/camera/public_html/simpleimage.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
```

Almost like the images couldn't be downloaded from the remote server.

**Again**
This script downloads all the images with no problems when ran from console, but when the cron runs nothing at all gets downloaded.

Thanks in advance guys.

**EDIT**
Another note.  I have another script downloading images from another server but it works fine.  This scripts is calling images using https, could that be the issue?

**EDIT2:**
code that saves the images

```
function save($filename, $image_type = IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression = 75, $permissions = null) {
    if ($image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) { imagejpeg($this -> image, $filename, $compression); //line 14
    } elseif ($image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {   imagegif($this -> image, $filename);
    } elseif ($image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {   imagepng($this -> image, $filename);
    }
    if ($permissions != null) {   chmod($filename, $permissions);
    }
```

code that calls that save

```
$simpleImage->save('/home/camera/public_html/app/webroot/upload/uploads/'.substr($id, 0, 1).'/'.substr($id, 1, 1).'/'.substr($id, 2, 1).'/' . $id . '-' . $name . '_original.jpg');
```

Comment: we need more code especially line 14 of simpleimage.php

Comment: Sounds like some env vars (path ?) are not initialised du to cron context...

Comment: Updated post with more info

Comment: As your cron user, change to the directory that normally runs the script and run the script using `nohup [command] &` from your console.  Monitor the process and check if it completes properly.

Comment: Everything works fine from the command line, but I ran your script anyways.  The script I run 
'/usr/bin/php /home/camera/public_html/feed.php "homenet_import" true'  so the command I ran was 'nohup /usr/bin/php /home/camera/public_html/feed.php "homenet_import" true &'
this was the response
 nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the real reason why, but the problem relieved it self once I changed the protocol from https to http..